# How to run sqlcmd.exe as a windows service?

Tags: process, sql-server, windows-services, vb.net, sql-server-express

Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)
Sep 24 2019 13:48:23
Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
**Express Edition** (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0  (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

I'm trying to run a sqlcmd command from within a windows service but nothing happens

Here is my command

```ps
sqlcmd -S mySQLserver\SQLEXPRESS -i D:\myscript.sql
```

Used NSSM to create a service
[image: NSSM1]
[image: NSSM2]
The service installs but upon starting the service it gives me an error
[image: NSSM_Error]

Used NSSM to do the same but this time to run a batch file that when executed runs the sqlcmd command. This installs and starts the service but doesn't do anything

Next is using NSSM to install a small VB.Net (VS 2019) app

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Execute_batch_file()
        Dim Process = New Process()
        Process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        Process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        Process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
        Process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        Process.StartInfo.FileName = "SQLCMD.EXE"
        Process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-S mySQLserver\SQLEXPRESS -i D:\myscript.sql
    "
        Process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "D:\"
    'I have put some stuff here to copy files from one place to another
            Process.Start()
    'I have put some stuff here to copy different files from one place to another
    End Sub
    
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Execute_batch_file()
    End Sub
    End Class
```

This installs as a Service and starts but doesn't do the SQLCMD process, however, the file copying before and after the `Process Start()` command works fine so the I know that the Service works.

I have also tried using Visual Studio to create the Service and I get the same results, everything work, timers, logging etc but not the SQLCMD process.

Finally... if I run the SQLCMD from the command line with the same parameters it works fine. If I run the batch file containing the SQLCMD command and parameters it works fine, just not through a Service.

I've trawled the forums and can't find anything similar apart from one post which didn't have any answers.

Any help would be appreciated

NSSM using direct access to SQLCMD and parameters
NSSM using batch file to run SQLCMD and parameters
NSSM using a compiled VB app to run a process (sql script in a batch file)
Visual Studio - Windows Service

Comment: Windows Services are for long-running (daemon) processes. You should probably be using Task Scheduler instead.

Comment: Agreed with @DanielB .. also .. to add.. you are 90% of the way there with the .net app.  Why not simply talk to the database that way and not worry about getting this Frankenstein monster to run?